# Comparing boolean in html not working as expected

Tags: html, angular7, ionic4

I have a flag called `isReadOnly` which I read value from query string parameter using the below statement.

`this.isReadOnly = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['isReadOnly'];`

I'm getting the value correctly but the issue is that comparing this flag in html or the negation of it is not working as expected.

for example look at the below code:
`isReadOnly:{{isReadOnly}} -->if true
    <br>
    isReadOnly==false:{{isReadOnly==false}} --> returns false which is correct`

but
`isReadOnly:{{isReadOnly}} --> if false
    <br>
    isReadOnly==false:{{isReadOnly==false}} --> returns false! its false == false, it should return true!`

this is happening in IONIC 4 Page

any help please?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you use it like this it works

```
isReadOnly==true? true :false
```

that mean if isReadOnly is true return true and if not return false.

Comment: I feel so stupid, my condition should be
`isReadOnly==false:{{isReadOnly=='false'}}` because I'm getting the flag from the query string.
thanks for your help.

Comment: the syntax get confusing sometime, this happens to everybody.

Comment: Well, sometimes it happens, if the answer was help full you can check it as correct.